# How do i loop thorugh all double positions to save all frames to hard disk?

Tags: c#

I'm using FrameGrabber.cs and I added its dll as reference: JockerSoft.Media.dll and Interop.qedit.

Now in Form1 code in the constructor I'm trying to retrieve all the frames in their position and save each frame to a new bitmap file on the hard disk but I can't figure out how to do it.

I don't know how to loop through all frames/double[] position I also wanted to see get information about how many frames there are I could get the framerate which is 17.8....

I want to get a list/array of all frames and then save each frame to hard disk and then do another manipulations on the frames.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ExtractVideoFrames.aspx?fid=273922&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=76#xx0xx) is the site i got the example from. Tried to look there and on source code but couldn't figure out how to do it.

** I also have a trackBar1 in the designer I wanted to be able to scroll through all frames which also doesn't work good.

This is my Form1 code which doesn't work good I can get only one frame.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ExtractFrames.Properties;
using ExtractFrames;
using JockerSoft.Media;
using JockerSoft;
using Interop.qedit;
using Interop;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ExtractFrames
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double x;
        string sf;
        double[] streamDouble ;
        string strVideoFile;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            sf = @"d:\Frames\";
            strVideoFile = @"d:\My Movie.wmv";
            for (int x = 0; x < 40; x++)
            {
                streamDouble = new double[x];
                SaveFramesFromVideo(strVideoFile, streamDouble, sf + x.ToString("D6") + ".bmp");
            }
            //getFrameRate();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private  void getFrameRate()
        {
            // Get framerate
            MediaDet md = new MediaDet();
            md.Filename = strVideoFile;
            //md.CurrentStream = 0;                     // choose the video stream
            x = md.FrameRate;
            double i = md.StreamLength;

        }

        public static void SaveFramesFromVideo(string videoFile, double[] positions, string outputBitmapFiles)
        {
            if (videoFile == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("videoFile");

            double streamLength;

            IMediaDet mediaDet = null;
            try
            {
                _AMMediaType mediaType;
                if (openVideoStream(videoFile, out mediaDet, out mediaType))
                {
                    streamLength = mediaDet.StreamLength;
                    Size target = getVideoSize(mediaType);
                    int iteration = 0;
                    foreach (double position in positions)
                    {
                        iteration++;
                        string outputBitmapFile = string.Format(outputBitmapFiles, iteration);
                        mediaDet.WriteBitmapBits(position, target.Width, target.Height, outputBitmapFile);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (COMException ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidVideoFileException();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (mediaDet != null)
                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mediaDet);
            }

            throw new InvalidVideoFileException("No video stream was found");
        }


        private static Size getVideoSize(_AMMediaType mediaType)
        {
            WinStructs.VIDEOINFOHEADER videoInfo = (WinStructs.VIDEOINFOHEADER)Marshal.PtrToStructure(mediaType.pbFormat, typeof(WinStructs.VIDEOINFOHEADER));

            return new Size(videoInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth, videoInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight);
        }

        private static Size scaleToFit(Size target, Size original)
        {
            if (target.Height * original.Width > target.Width * original.Height)
                target.Height = target.Width * original.Height / original.Width;
            else
                target.Width = target.Height * original.Width / original.Height;

            return target;
        }
        private static Size scaleToFitSmart(Size target, Size original)
        {
            target = scaleToFit(target, original);

            if (target.Width > original.Width || target.Height > original.Height)
                return original;

            return target;
        }


        private static bool openVideoStream(string videoFile, out IMediaDet mediaDet, out _AMMediaType aMMediaType)
        {
            mediaDet = new MediaDet();

            //loads file
            mediaDet.Filename = videoFile;

            //gets # of streams
            int streamsNumber = mediaDet.OutputStreams;

            //finds a video stream
            for (int i = 0; i < streamsNumber; i++)
            {
                mediaDet.CurrentStream = i;
                _AMMediaType mediaType = mediaDet.StreamMediaType;

                if (mediaType.majortype == JockerSoft.Media.MayorTypes.MEDIATYPE_Video)
                {
                    //video stream found
                    aMMediaType = mediaType;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            //no video stream found
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mediaDet);
            mediaDet = null;
            aMMediaType = new _AMMediaType();
            return false;
        }



    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SaveFramesFromVideo()` method expects a double array filled with the *percentage* position in the file in seconds - since you don't know how this relates to the length of the video you cannot use the frame rate alone. You can however save a frame at each full percentage into the file:

```
var streamDouble = new double[1];
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
{
    streamDouble[0] = x;
    SaveFramesFromVideo(strVideoFile, streamDouble, sf + x.ToString("D6") + ".bmp");
}
```

If you just need that for WMV files you could also use [AsfMojo](http://asfmojo.codeplex.com/) instead - a complete solution would then look like this:

```
AsfFile asfFile = new AsfFile(@"D:\samples\sample.wmv");
AsfFileProperties fileProperties = asfFile.GetAsfObject<AsfFileProperties>();
TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.FromTicks((long)fileProperties.PlayDuration) - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(fileProperties.Preroll);

var streamProps = asfFile.GetAsfObjects<AsfExtendedStreamProperties>()
                         .SingleOrDefault(x => x.StreamNumber == asfFile.PacketConfiguration.AsfVideoStreamId);

double timePerFrame = streamProps.AvgTimePerFrame / (double) 10000000 ;

double offset = 0;
while (offset < duration.TotalSeconds)
{
    using (var bitmap = AsfImage.FromFile(@"D:\samples\sample.wmv").AtOffset(offset))
    {
        if(bitmap!=null)
            bitmap.Save(string.Format(@"d:\Frames\{0}.jpg", offset.ToString("N")), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
    offset += timePerFrame;
}
```

Comment: BrokenGlass its working but there are more then 100 frames. Is there any way to get the number of frames first or the video length and then use it instead 100 ? Thanks.

Comment: @DanielLip: You can restructure the existing code a little to do that - look in the `SaveFramesFromVideo()` method - `streamLength = mediaDet.StreamLength;` is the stream length - given that you can just advance an offset by the frameRate until you reach the stream length

Comment: BrokenGlass i need this for 3gp files from my android phone. But also for wma and avi. Ill try to do what you sai " You can restructure the existing code a little to do that - look in the SaveFramesFromVideo() method - streamLength = mediaDet.StreamLength; is the stream length - given that you can just advance an offset by the frameRate until you reach the stream length " not sure how yet but ill try.